# Перегрузка опертора [] c++ для создания двумерного массива

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Есть класс, который хранит в себе двумерный массив `QVector<T>`(Аналог `std::vector<T>` в Qt)

```
class Field : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Field(int width = 0, int height = 0);

    QVector<int>& operator[](int n) {return (v_field.begin()[n]);}

private:
    int width, height;
    QVector< QVector<int> > v_field;

};
```

То как я перегрузил `operator[]` видно в коде выше. Вопрос: как присвоить значение `QVector< QVector<int> > v_field`, через экземпляр класса `Field`. Т.е. если сделать так:

```
field[0][0] = 0; // Экземпляр класса Field
```

А потом вывести

```
qDebug() << "<<<<<<<<<<" << this->field[0][0];
```

Получаю старое значение. Т.е. `field[0][0] = 0` не меняет `v_field`. (А я хочу чтобы получилось аналогично `v_field[0][0] = 0`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QVector<int>& operator[](int n) {return v_field[n];}
const QVector<int>& operator[](int n) const {return v_field[n];}
```

Возможно, также стоит добавить ассерты для проверки выхода за пределы вектора.